# Grouping JSON array with given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I have a set of JSON data which was being populated via WordPress Ajax.

```
["http://inovar.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/FR991-Eco-Oak-A1.jpg",…]
```

The total of item at this moment is 69. How could I group it into 18 items per set. Then wrap it like this:

```
<div class="slide">
<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/BG_2-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/BG_2-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/BG_2-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/BG_2-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/BG_2-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/BG_2-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var urls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22];
var href = function (url) {
    return '<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="' + url + '" alt=""/></a>\r\n'
}
var groupLimit = 18;
var output = urls.reduce(function (htmlString, current, index) {
    var mod = index %groupLimit;
    if (mod === 0) { 
  if (index >= groupLimit) htmlString += '</div>\r\n';
        htmlString += '<div class="slide">\r\n'
    }
    return htmlString + href(current)
}, '') + '</div>';
console.log(output)
```

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [the remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
var arr = ["http://inovar.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/FR991-Eco-Oak-A1.jpg",…];

var itemsPerBlock = 18;

var htmlStr = '<div class="slide">'
arr.forEach( function (d, idx) {
    htmlStr += '<a class="floor-thumbnail"><img src="' +
               d.split('inovar.dev')[1] + 
               '" alt=""/></a>';

    if ((idx+1) % itemsPerBlock == 0 ) 
        htmlStr += '</div><div class="slide">';
})

htmlStr += '</div>';

$('body').append(htmlStr); //append this to body
```

Comment: Hi surajck, let me try.. ya.

Comment: If it worked, please upvote and mark the answer as correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
     0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
    20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39
],
items = 18;

var parent = document.body // or parent


for ( var i=0; i < arr.length; i++ )
{
    if ( i % items == 0 )
    {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.classList.add('slide');
        parent.appendChild( el )
    }
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.classList.add('floor-thumbnail');
    el.appendChild( a );
 
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = arr[i];
    a.appendChild( img )
}
```